# Error in JWT Remote Authentication using NetCore 2

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I currently have two different projects, one the MainAPI, that will expose the functions for my web client, and another one, the AuthAPI, which handles all the the auth requests, all built using netcore 2.

If I call the AuthAPI directly, it will handle requests as desired.

When I try to have the MainAPI requests be authenticated by the AuthAPI, it fails to do so, although I can see the requests comming in and out the AuthAPI.

Here is my services authentication configuration in MainAPI Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5019/auth/api/info";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5019";
                    options.Audience = AUDIENCE;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;

                    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new BackChannelHttpHandler();

                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                });
```

Here is BackChannelHttpHandler class:

```
public class BackChannelHttpHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

           HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(), disposeHandler: false);          
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var res = await client.GetAsync(request.RequestUri);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

And the controller I am calling as the Authorize annotation as follows:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

As for the AuthAPI, I have Cors configured in Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsConfig",
                        builder => builder
                           .AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowCredentials()
                           .Build());
});
```

In AuthAPI controller I have also the `[EnableCors("CorsConfig")]` Annotation.

I can get the call to the AuthAPI controller, and it returns a HTTP-200, but in my MainAPI something in the authorization process gets called that Unauthorizes it and my call to the MainAPI controller never gets executed.

My questio is, what am I doing wrong in the MainAPI authentication process, that authenticates by itself the token, and invalidates the request.

Comment: Do you call AuthAPI from the MainAPI server? How the call looks like?

Answer (score 0):

pay attention for this parameter options.Audience; 
it should have available end-points.

or you can share a key between applications for more productivity. Each end-point can read payload from token, but only auth-server can produce tokens.

Comment: As far as I know, Audience could be any string. I use "Users" with success, including CORS calls.